# Question on relation between convex sets

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, polytopes

The book I am referring regarding bell inequalites has the following two things it mentions about two convex sets which I am unable to understand. There are two convex sets  $C$ ($C$ is a polytope ) and $Q$. The book says

1. $Q$ is a convex set but not closed. What does it mean ? Is it a convex set
   with infinite extreme points ?
2. There is some relation because of which it comes out that $Q \subset C$. But in the next theorem the author proves $Q$ contains the interior of $C$. How is it different from the condition $Q \subset C$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) An open ball is a simple example of a convex set which is not closed. The only requirement for convexity is that a line between any two points in the set remains in the set. Clearly, that doesn't imply closure!

2) If $Q\subset C$, that doesn't imply that $Q$ contains the whole interior of $C$. If I have a ball of radius $r$, then a ball of radius $r/2$ could fit inside it. Thus the smaller ball is a subset of the larger ball. But the smaller ball certainly doesn't contain the whole interior of the larger one!

Comment: could you elaborate about closure in your first point ?

Comment: So closure means a set contains all its exterior points. An open ball doesn't contain ANY of its exterior points. But an open ball is still a convex set: every line between two points of the ball stays within the ball. So from that example, you should be able to see that convex doesn't imply closed.